# Merge RDS files from two different file paths?

Tags: r

Folder 1 and Folder 2 are full of .rds files. How would I go about merging all files in both folders into 1 .rds file?

What I have so far

```
mergedat <- do.call('rbind', lapply(list.files("File/Path/To/Folder/1/", full.names = TRUE), readRDS))
```

However I don't know how to add the second file path and even then, the code above does not seem to be working.

The information in the .rds files are all set up exactly the same as far as number of columns and column headers go, but the information in them is obviously different. I just figured out that I did not have the files read either within my code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is in the .RDS files?

Comment: maybe `list.files("File/Path/To/Folder/", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = '\\.rds$')` assuming `Folder` doesn't contain any rds files you don't want to read

Comment: @rawr I do want them read, and put into 1 file. Will specify that in edit

Comment: @rpolicastro read my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this twice, each time for a different `path`:

```
path <- "./files"
files <- list.files(path = path,
                    full.names = TRUE,
                    all.files = FALSE)
files <- files[!file.info(files)$isdir]

data <- lapply(files,
               function(x) {
                 readRDS(x)
               })
```

You end up with 2 data objects which are lists with each list element containing a data frame that corresponds with what is in the RDS file. If all those files are the same in terms if structure, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows()` to concatenate all data frames into one combined data frame.